# How can I create a function to find the average of a list?

Tags: python, function, average, user-defined-functions, create-function

I'm trying to create a functional for the average of a list that accepts three parameters: a mandatory list of numbers, an optional minimum value which defaults to zero, and an an optional maximum value which defaults to 100. The function should only calculate the average of values between the stated minimum and maximum, even if there are other vaues in the list.

```
def avgList(lst, low = 0, high = 100):
    """Calculates the average of a list of values"""
    for i in range(low, high):
        avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
        return avg
```

This is what I tried. I also have a few sample outputs I tried, it worked for the first two but not for the third.
The first is asking for the mean of a list from 1 to 10

```
lst1 = list(range(1,11))
average1 = avglist(lst1)
average1
```

The second is asking for the mean of the numbers between 20 and 80 in a list from 1 to 100.

```
lst2 = list(range(1, 101))
average2 = avglist(lst2, 19, 80)
average2
```

The third is asking for a mean of all the numbers between 30 and 100 in a randomly generated list of 100 numbers between 1 and 100. I would expect the mean to be around 65, but it usually ends up around 50

```
lst3 = [] 
for i in range(1, 100):   
    n = random.randint(1, 100)   
    lst3.append(n) 
average3 = avglist(lst3, 29, 100)
average3
```

Comment: Your sample code uses the values `low` and `high` in a completely wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

Your `for i in range(low,high)` really doesn't make any sense. Inside that loop it calculates the average for the full `lst` and immediately returns the first result (the first time it hits `return` on the first iteration, it does so and the function ends).

Instead, rebuild your list and reject any elements that fall outside of your `low`/`high` bounds, then take the average of that:

```
def avgList(lst, low = 0, high = 100):
    """Calculates the average of a list of values"""
    truncated_list = [x for x in lst if (x>low and x<high)]    
    avg = sum(truncated_list)/len(truncated_list)
    return avg
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry if this question was basic, I'm a student who's learning his first programming language.

Comment: I figured this was homework. Thanks for including your non-working code. It was a well written question. Best of luck in your studies!

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not do what you want at all, you do not filter the values from `lst` at all, there is point at iterating on the range from low to high

---

What you want is

```
def avgList(lst, low = 0, high = 100):
    """Calculates the average of a list of values"""
    valid_values = [x for x in lst if low <= x <= high]
    return sum(valid_values) / len(valid_values)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Sorry if this question was basic, I'm a student who's very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
.... The function should only calculate the average of values between the stated minimum and maximum, even if there are other vaues in the list.
```

You can declare two variables, one that keeps count and one for the sum. Then just loop through the list of numbers and only take in account those numbers that fit your criteria:

```
def avgList(nums: list, low: int, high: int):
    sum = 0
    counter = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n >= low and n <= high:
            sum += n
            counter += 1
    
    return sum/counter
```